# HTML vertical navbar height up to the footer

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have this layout when the size of screen is greater than 768px:
[image]

But I want the vertical navbar height up to the footer even when resize the screen.
This is what I want:[image]

with the background color obviously.

This is html file and css file!

```css
article {
 text-align: left;
}

header {
 background: black; 
 color: white;
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}

nav {
 background: #eee;
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}

ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0; /*Tolgo il padding da ul*/
}

li a{
 display: block; /* Separo per riga i padding*/
 padding: 8px 16px;
 color: #000; /* Rimuovo il classico colore viola del link*/
 text-decoration: none; /*rimuovo la sottilineatura del link*/
 
}

li a:hover { /* Cosa fare quando il mouse si trova sopra*/
 background-color: #555;
 color: white;
}

footer{
 background: #aaa;
 color: white;
 padding: 0px;
}

img{
 padding: 10px;
  height: 505px;
  width: 829px;
}

/*Riposiziono gli elementi se la larghezza è >=768px per tutti i dispositivi*/
@media all and (min-width: 768px){
 
 nav {
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 200px;
  float: left; /*Sposto il contenuto a destra*/
 }

 article {
  margin-left: 250px;
 }


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Index.css">
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <header>
   <h1 id="T">Index</h1>
  </header>
  
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a>Topologie</a></li>
    <li><a>Classificazione</a></li>
    <li><a>Dizionario terminologico</a></li>
    <li><a href="Pagine\Domini.html">Domini</a></li>
    <li><a>Apparati</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  
  <article>
   <h2>Definizione di Rete</h2>
   Una rete di telecomunicazioni è un insieme di dispositivi e dei loro collegamenti 
   (fisici o logici) che consentono la trasmissione e la ricezione di informazioni di 
   qualsiasi tipo tra due o più utenti situati in posizioni geograficamente distinte, 
   effettuandone il trasferimento attraverso cavi, sistemi radio o altri sistemi elettromagnetici 
   o ottici.

  <br><br><img src="Immagini/ImmagineRete.png">

  </article>

  <footer>
   <p>Ultimo aggiornamento: Sabato 19 Maggio</p>
   <p><a href="#T">Torna all'inizio</a></p>
  </footer>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

I want this behavior:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_layout_flexbox

In the example above the navbar height expands to the footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will wrap the `nav` and the `article` inside `main` tag and give it `display: flex` and it will take the **highest** `height` and also remove the `float` from the `nav` you don't need it as long as you are using `dispaly:flex` by default its `flex-direction:row` they will be next to each other

```
<main>
 <nav></nav>
 <article></article>
</main>
```

```css
 
p { margin: 0; }

article {
    text-align: left;
  }

  header {
    background: black; 
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  nav {
    background: #eee;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0; /*Tolgo il padding da ul*/
  }

  li a{
    display: block; /* Separo per riga i padding*/
    padding: 8px 16px;
    color: #000; /* Rimuovo il classico colore viola del link*/
    text-decoration: none; /*rimuovo la sottilineatura del link*/

  }

  li a:hover { /* Cosa fare quando il mouse si trova sopra*/
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
  }

  footer{
    background: #aaa;
    color: white;
    padding: 0px;
  }

  img{
    padding: 10px;
    height: 505px;
    width: 829px;
  }

  /*Riposiziono gli elementi se la larghezza è >=768px per tutti i dispositivi*/
  @media all and (min-width: 768px){

      main {
         display: flex;
      }

    nav {
      text-align: left;
      max-width: 200px;
      margin-right: 50px;
    }
  }
```

```html
    

      <header>
       <h1 id="T">Index</h1>
      </header>
      
      <main>
          <nav>
       <ul>
        <li><a>Topologie</a></li>
        <li><a>Classificazione</a></li>
        <li><a>Dizionario terminologico</a></li>
        <li><a href="Pagine\Domini.html">Domini</a></li>
        <li><a>Apparati</a></li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
      
      <article>
       <h2>Definizione di Rete</h2>
       Una rete di telecomunicazioni è un insieme di dispositivi e dei loro collegamenti 
       (fisici o logici) che consentono la trasmissione e la ricezione di informazioni di 
       qualsiasi tipo tra due o più utenti situati in posizioni geograficamente distinte, 
       effettuandone il trasferimento attraverso cavi, sistemi radio o altri sistemi elettromagnetici 
       o ottici.

      <br><br><img src="Immagini/ImmagineRete.png">

      </article>
        </main>

      <footer>
       <p>Ultimo aggiornamento: Sabato 19 Maggio</p>
       <p><a href="#T">Torna all'inizio</a></p>
      </footer>
      
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Perfect, it was what I wanted. It was hours that I was looking for a solution. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Chuck94 you're welcome we are here to help each other ;) so happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of your nav to the height of the current screen size, I'm pretty sure this will do the job.

```
nav {
background: #eee;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Don't work, the navbar height isn't above the footer. Can you edit my question e edit the code snippet and than run and see that your answer don't work. Test!